# How do I select a single row by value of column[0] in pandas data frame fast and easy

Tags: python, pandas

I have loaded a two column csv file in pandas data frame that has a unique key in column[0] (integer index) of every row and a value in column[1] of every row.  It has no header.

I want simply to look up the single value in column[1] (or the whole row series) by using a key to match against the value column[0] to locate the row.

of course efficient etc.  As if it were a dictionary with the string keys like  value = dict.get(key)

example csv file:

```
a, "valueForA"
x, "valueForX"
z, "valueForZ"
```

...

```
df = pandas.read_csv(fileAbove)

row = df.wayToFindRowByColumn0Value('x')  # row is a series of 2 elements

row[0] should be the key 'x'
row[1] should be 'valueForX'

row = df.wayToFindRowByColumn0Value('notThere')  # row should be None if not found
```

Comment: Add small example dataset and what you expected output is. [How to make a good reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to store the values as a simple pandas `Series` (rather than a data frame) using the key field as index and the value field as series values. This can be achieved by calling the `read_csv` method in this way (some details are from [the OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57454160/10157759)).

```
s = pd.read_csv('/data/companyDataByCusip.csv', encoding='utf_8', names=['cusip','value'], index_col='cusip', squeeze=True)
```

Now you can access the `Series` just like a dictionary:

```
val = s[key]
```

If a data frame is really needed, you could remove the `squeeze` argument from `read_csv` and access the value using `df.at[key,'value']`.

Comment: thanks another way - works great for single values in a row.

Answer (score 1):

Use `df.at[index, column]`. [See documentation here.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html#pandas.DataFrame.at)

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[{'value': x*x} for x in range(10)], 
                  index=[x for x in range(10)])
print(df)
print('At 4: {}'.format(df.at[4, 'value']))
```

Output:

```
   value
0      0
1      1
2      4
3      9
4     16
5     25
6     36
7     49
8     64
9     81

At 4: 16
```

---

Update:

To get a dataframe as a return, can try something like this:

```
row = df[df.index.values == 4]
print(row)
```

Output:

```
   value
4     16
```

Comment: almost right except I want to get the row series or value in integer indexed column [1]  for the row with the non-integer string name in column[0] of the row.  df.at takes two non integer lookup names, and df.iat takes two integer indices like indexing a matrix.

Comment: Does it need to be a pandas Series?  Or can you just build your own list?  ie: `row = [4, df.at[4, 'value']]`

Comment: no I could parse and use a dict or other map type.  I have been asked to do this in pandas.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
df[df.column0==key].column1.iloc[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `loc` can do th e job:

```
df.loc[[integer index]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok poking around looks like using .loc() is the way but it reqires you set a column explicitly as the row index field, and a set explicit column names.  It works, though I havn't speed tested it.

The doc I found is here:

https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/04/pandas-dataframe-indexing.html

```
#  read in the file of the cusip database to a data frame
df = pandas.read_csv('/data/companyDataByCusip.csv',encoding='utf_8', names=['cusip','value'])
df.set_index('cusip',inplace=True)

rec = df.loc[cusip,:]
print(rec) # series for row
```